# Collar Tie coming loose from rafter?

Tags: roof, roofing, truss

What should I do about this collar tie, all the nails seem to be coming out of the rafter or were not in correctly to begin with?
[image: collar truss connected by nail tips]

Added photo showing nails

[image: Enhanced brightness]

Comment: Should there be such a large gap between the nails and the beam? Seems like they could pop out.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like what you're asking about is a collar tie nailing to a rafter.  I don't think your roof is going to collapse from one of those being loose.

Can't tell from the pictures what's making it come off like that but if there's nothing else wrong I would either hammer them back or pull them back together with a clamp.  You could also extract the nails neatly with a cat's paw and drive 3" construction screws through the nail holes.  Do this one nail at a time to keep things aligned.

Might want to wait for some 2nd opinions or at least some upvotes for this answer before you follow that advice.  I'm not a structural engineer or a carpenter.

Comment: Thanks I updated the question title

Comment: Insert some glue/construction adhesive, pound the nails back in, put a couple screws in from the other side. 3" will stick out the points and bite, 2-1/2" is fine. 2-3/4" if you can find them, but that's not a common size. Nails have more shear strength.

Comment: "nails have more shear strength" - very true unless you upgrade to the newer, much more expensive "structural screws" that are designed for this purpose and have the shear strength necessary. A couple of "regular" screws in addition to the nails is a great idea. Nails for shear, screws for clamping power.